# ruby on rails 4/jquery/javascript: button only works after page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

EDIT: see my own response on an interpretation of what was going on. Any RoR expert welcome to provide a good explanation of what's going on.

I have no error message in my browser console (firefox and chromium). Javascript/jquery doesn't work when I go via link but on reload ALL IS FINE. ?????

You can see this bug in action at

http://new.mapmill.org:3000/

Click "Browse sites" in the header section, then choose "Medellín" as an image set (only currently existing one). You'll be redirected to this image set.

Click either "Upload more pictures for this site" or "View Map" - nothing happens.
If you reload the page, "The upload more pictures for this site" works (you'll be redirected to login but that's fine).

Seems javascript is not being loaded fine on this page and jquery is not working at all. What could be going wrong if I don't have any error message, and on reload all is just fine?

EDIT: The app is a ruby on rails application. The buttons are not dynamically loaded, here is the relevant show.html.erb file section for the two buttons:

```
<h1>Site details</h1>
<div class="site_information">
<h2 style="display: inline-block; margin-right: 20px"><%= @site.name %></h2><div class="site_img_num"><%= @site.images.count %> images</div>
<button style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px" id="upload_more" class="btn btn-primary">Upload more pictures for this site</button>
<button style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px" id="show_map" class="btn btn-success">View Map</button>

 <%= hidden_field_tag 'site_id', @site.id %>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: What's the name of your .js file where you want to handle this action?

Comment: hmmmm I understand these comments but do you really want me to post my whole javascript file stack???? I wouldn't even know where to start!!! There is no error message and there are hundreds of lines of javascript code. Thanks so much to those folks like @Cerbrus who at least are polite in their comments and/or provide meaningful help instead of herd mentality downvoting. It's also a ruby on rails app serving the javascript, in which case then I'd have to share my whole project in order to look for the needle in the haystack. I was more looking for suggestions on where to look for.

Comment: @MZeinstra it's sites.js

Comment: for example @Leo's and Timofey 's answers are very helpful. I don't need someone to solve my problem, just hints on where to look for :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 433 of http://new.mapmill.org:3000/assets/sites.js

```
$('#upload_more').click(function() {
  return window.location.href = '/sites/' + $('#site_id').val() + "/upload";
});
```

You are binding the event handler on DOM ready, but your page content is loaded dynamically. So at the time you binding the event, `$('#upload_more')` doesn't even exist in the DOM.

In my experences this is commonly happened when someone is developing a single page app (aka SPA) for the first time. Check the bound events in devtool (Event Listeners tab in Elements), and you will find something is wrong.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Leo for all the time you took for crafting this response, letting along looking at the code! My app is not a single page app, it's a ruby on rails app. I'll provide the html in the post. Your response has been pretty helpful, at least I have a path on where to look for. The button is not loaded dynamically but maybe I need to look for more of that stuff. I wish I could upvote this more.

Comment: @faboolous it doesn't matter what is your backend. SPA is a phrase refers to frontend. As I noticed you are using AngularJS, and observed the network tab from devtool, I'm pretty sure about that. You would better bind the event on ng routing, which triggers dynamic content load.

Comment: I regularly use angular when working with nodejs but this project needed to be in ruby on rails and I did not know how to use angular with RoR :) So no, no angular. But I am pretty sure that what you are saying will lead me to the solution, it's probably some dynamic loading stuff. Thank you @Leo

Comment: Please see my own response on how I resolved it. Your response though brought me on track so I accepted yours.

Answer (score 1):

I can't open your link but I think that the problem is because your html is created dynamically. If so you have to attach all event listeners after creation or use delegated events attached to some elements which are not loaded dynamically ($(document).on(...) in simple case).
See details here http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a common Turbolinks issue.  It's well worth reading their documentation to understand what it does to your js files and document ready functions.  [Turbolinks on Github](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks)

Here's the summary of how you can work around this if it turns out to be Turbolinks.

The first is this workaround for your js which has been passed around SO quite a bit.

```
var ready;

ready = function(){
  //your js scripts go here
};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

OR you can update the link_to helper you are using to get to this page to skip turbolinks when loading the page:

```
<%= link_to "Where you're going", add_product_path, data: { no_turbolink: true } %>
```

OR you can try the `'jquery-turbolinks'` gem but you will likely need to spend some time with their documentation to make sure you have implemented it correctly (i.e. it's not just a copy paste and bundle update kind of experience).

Answer (score 0):

It probably comes down on myself not correctly understanding of how Ruby on Rails and the asset pipeline work. I still do not really understand it. But indeed it seems RoR handles an app kind of a single app.

So when I land on the home page, $(document).ready is run. At that point, #upload_more does not yet exist as I did not load the site listing, and the click binding does not apply.

When I go to the site listing, the page DOES NOT GET RELOADED again, and thus the binding does not work either for some reason.

I solved it this way:

```
<button style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="window.location.href='/sites/<%= @site.id %>/upload'" id="upload_more" class="btn btn-primary">Upload more pictures for this site</button>

<button style="margin-left: 20px; padding: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px" onclick="window.location.href='/sites/<%= @site.id %>/map'" id="show_map" class="btn btn-success">View map</button>
```

Thus adding the action inline in the button. It is perfectly ok for my needs and doesn't need any jquery binding.

If any Ruby On Rails guru at some point would chime in and provide some good explanation that'd be awesome, for future reference.

I apologize for the poor quality of the question as it comes down to myself using a technology I am not proficient with. Always learning...

Comment: So uh... it looks like a workaround. You are redirecting onclick to force a page unload/load. So what prevents it from refreshing? I'm not familiar with Ruby but if you find the root cause do remember to leave a comment here :)

Comment: By the way you didn't use AngularJS, although you have `ng-app`, my bad.